# How to find absolute value of caret position in pixels using Cocoa in MacOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa

For mouse I'm using:

```
ourEvent = CGEventCreate(None);
currentpos = CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);
```

What can I use for the caret?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Your question makes me thing you have an ["XY Problem"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the bad news.

Not every app is Cocoa-based, and those that are neither Cocoa nor Carbon nor a straight mix of the two—i.e., those based on wxWidgets, Qt, or some other cross-platform framework—typically reimplement the entire GUI stack on top of raw event and drawing primitives.

That means that there is typically no way to get this information from those applications (unless they're scriptable and expose it that way).

The good news is, Cocoa apps and *some* Carbon apps may expose this via Accessibility.

The user will need to have assistive devices turned on in System Preferences. Once that condition is met, you can use the Accessibility framework to get the frontmost application, get its focused window, get its focused view, and get its selection ranges.

A text view with an insertion point has exactly one selection range, and that range is empty (length=0). The location is where the insertion point is.

Of course, those are character indexes, not on-screen bounds.

That's where parameterized attributes come in. There's one for converting ranges to bounds. That's the one you want.

*Theoretically* (I haven't tried this), you should be able to convert the empty range of the insertion point to an empty or nearly-empty rectangle whose location is somewhere within the vertical line of the insertion point.

Make sure you test this with text views that are in scroll views, particularly when the insertion point is scrolled partially or completely out of view.

---

You'll want to use the Accessibility Inspector to see for yourself where your application will need to look, and to test individual applications and investigate reported failures.

You can get it from [the Developer Downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/), in the “Accessibility Tools” disk image.

---

If you want to focus a window, forging a mouse event to click on it is a bad idea—anything can happen if you click on the wrong thing. Send the window an `kAXRaiseAction` action instead.

If you want to *set* a text view's insertion point (and are looking to find where you need to forge a mouse event to click to set it in the desired position), again, that's a bad way to do it. Set the view's `kAXSelectedTextRangesAttribute` attribute instead. Again, an insertion point is a single empty range.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there is and _easy_ and generic way to do that, but after hours of googling and your answer it doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: If the range is empty you cannot get the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this below?

```
NSPoint p=[[NSApp currentEvent]locationInWindow];
CGFloat X=p.x;
CGFloat Y=p.y;
NSLog(@"%f %f",X,Y);
```

Comment: This does not provide the caret location, only mouse locations.